# NET 7 published single file not running after port from NET Framework 4.6

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2022, .net-framework-version, .net-7.0

i created a little winforms app some years ago with the NET framework 4.6 that now needed some rework. I had to decompile it with jetbeans dotpeak as the source code got lost over the years (what worked very well) and ported it to NET 7 (what also worked well despite some little changes i had to do).
So i could do my work with it in visual studio 2022, debug and test ... all that works but if i want to publish it as a single file the app wont run. No error or anything it just doesnt run. If i publish it with all the dlls visible it works. Its not a major thing but i wonder what might be the cause. It seems that the program library which will be normally created, will not be put in the file when using single file deployment but thats just a guess. I also did some other apps with NET 7 where single file deployment works fine so it might have something to do with the port? Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks :)

I published the app using single file deployment -> app doesnt run without any error.

I published the app without single file deployment -> an additional dll (with the app name) is created and the app runs well.

Comment: I would create a brand new app, make sure the single file deployment works, check it in to a git repo and then add your old code bit by bit till you've copied it all over or found what has broken it.